# Using enum friendly Name

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use enum in a user friendly readable name 
But I cant find out how to bound it to my view's

This is what I have so far   :

```
public enum MyDayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    SunTilFir = 7,

}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public MyDayOfWeek Days { get; set; }
}

public static class ChangeEnumName
{
    public static string EnumValue(this MyDayOfWeek e)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case MyDayOfWeek.SunTilFir:
                return "Sunday until Friday ";
        }
        return "Horrible Failure!!";
    }
}
```

How can I bind the ChangeEnum name to my view?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an extension method for an enumerated type. I don't think that's valid in C#.

Comment: What is the way to do it ? using friendly name with enum?

Comment: Use bit-values and create a value `Weekdays` which can be written as `Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday` or `~Saturday & ~Sunday`? Although I can't say I'm sure what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Would you mind using resource strings to use the enum value strings as a lookup key?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is make a readonly property on your model from which you return your FriendlyName

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public MyDayOfWeek Days { get; set; }

    public string DaysFriendlyName
    {
         get
         {
              switch(this.Days)
              {
                  case MyDayOfWeek.SunTilFir:
                         return "Sunday until Friday ";
              }
              return "Horrible Failure!!";
         }
     }
}
```

Probably even better to not implement the switch in the body of your readonly property, but maybe make an extensions method for it? So your body will look like this:

```
public string DaysFriendlyName
{
    get
    {
         return this.Days.ToFriendlyName();
    }
}
```

And the extension method:

```
namespace UniPro.Models
{    
    public static class DaysEnumExtensions
    {
         public static string ToFriendlyName(this MyDayOfWeek days)
         {
              switch (days)
              {
               //....
              }
         }
     }
}
```

The nice part of the extension method would be that you could loose the readonly property and bind directly to the extension method from your razor view (put in the correct 'using' in your razor view for this to work).

Comment: What namespace Should I use for the "@Using" ?

Comment: Just add the using for the `DaysEnumExtensions` class. Do note that extension methods cannot be used with controltemplates like DisplayFor<>. In that case you'll need the readonly property

Comment: @using UniPro.Models.DaysEnumExtensions Im getting this Error: A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'UniPro.Models.DaysEnumExtensions' is a type not a namespace

Comment: So your namespace is UniPro.Models? Then the using should be @using UniPro.Models. See my edit in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it like this:

```
public enum MyDayOfWeek
{
    [UserFriendlyName("Sunday")]
    Sunday = 0,

    [UserFriendlyName("Monday")]
    Monday = 1,

    [UserFriendlyName("Tuesday")]
    Tuesday = 2,

    [UserFriendlyName("Wednesday")]
    Wednesday = 3,

    [UserFriendlyName("Thursday")]
    Thursday = 4,

    [UserFriendlyName("Friday")]
    Friday = 5,

    [UserFriendlyName("Saturday")]
    Saturday = 6,

    [UserFriendlyName("Sunday until Friday")]
    SunTilFir = 7
}

public class UserFriendlyNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public UserFriendlyNameAttribute(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserFriendlyName(this MyDayOfWeek myDayOfWeek)
    {
        return GetUserFriendlyNameAttributeText(typeof(MyDayOfWeek), myDayOfWeek.ToString());
    }

    private static string GetUserFriendlyNameAttributeText(this Type type, string memberName)
    {
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(memberName);
        if (memInfo.Length == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserFriendlyNameAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
            return null;

        return ((UserFriendlyNameAttribute) attributes[0]).Text;
    }
}
```

So you can use it in a view as extension method:

```
MyDayOfWeek.SunTilFir.GetUserFriendlyName()
```